# UITableView UITableViewCellStyle.Value1 TextLabel is overlapping the DetailTextLabel

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin iOS and on iOS 9.2 devices the UITableView cells with cell style of UITableViewCellStyle.Value1 have the TextLabel overlapping the DetailTextLabel.

This doesn't happen on iOS 8. Anybody know what I can do to fix it without rolling my own cell? I just would like the TextLabel to ellipsis instead of overlapping the DetailTextLabel.

[image: Image showing text overlapping]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a fix. A blank project reproduced it with just a simple TableView so I rolled my own custom cell.

```
public class CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
        UILabel headingLabel, subheadingLabel;

        public MTableViewCell (NSString cellId) : base (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
        {
            SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Default;
            headingLabel = new UILabel ();
            subheadingLabel = new UILabel () {
                TextColor = UIColor.Gray,
                TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center
            };
            ContentView.AddSubviews (new UIView[] { headingLabel, subheadingLabel });
        }

        public override void LayoutSubviews ()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews ();
            headingLabel.Frame = new CGRect (15, 0, ContentView.Bounds.Width - 130, ContentView.Bounds.Height);
            subheadingLabel.Frame = new CGRect (ContentView.Bounds.Width - 110, 0, 95, ContentView.Bounds.Height);
        }

        public override UILabel TextLabel {
            get {
                return headingLabel;
            }
        }

        public override UILabel DetailTextLabel {
            get {
                return subheadingLabel;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible just to set a new `Frame` for `TextLable` & `DetailTextLable` in `public override void LayoutSubviews ()`, instead of create 2 new labels?

Comment: @Fei that might be a possibility too. I haven't checked.

Answer (score 0):

Pasudocode to decide if you want to dequeue value1 or sub type of cell

```
public static func isVerticalLayout(primary: String, secondary: NSAttributedString,
                                    liveHostView: UIView) -> Bool
{
    let csWidth = liveHostView.bounds.width

    let headingLabel = UILabel()
    let subheadingLabel = UILabel()
    headingLabel.text = primary
    headingLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    headingLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    subheadingLabel.attributedText = secondary
    subheadingLabel.textAlignment = .right
    subheadingLabel.numberOfLines = 1
    subheadingLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

    let clipw =  csWidth - P97GEL.Constants.leftTextMargin - P97GEL.Constants.rightTextMargin
    let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: clipw, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let psRect = headingLabel.textRect(forBounds: bounds, limitedToNumberOfLines: 1)
    let ps = psRect.size
    let ssRect = subheadingLabel.textRect(forBounds: bounds, limitedToNumberOfLines: 1)
    let ss = ssRect.size

    headingLabel.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: P97GEL.Constants.leftTextMargin, y: P97GEL.Constants.verticalMargin)
    headingLabel.frame.size = ps
    subheadingLabel.frame.size = ss

    if csWidth >= ps.width + ss.width + (3 * P97GEL.Constants.horizontalMargin) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```